# node/mongo response after loop

Tags: node.js, mongodb, promise

how would i return the total as resolve(total) when the loop is done?

what would be the way to do it?

```
function getTotalAttack(minions) {
    return new Promise( function (resolve, reject) {
        console.log("starting do the totalattack math");

        var total = 0;
        for(var minion in minions) {
            console.log("sending one now");

            minions.findOne({ _Id  : minion }).then(function(response){
                total = total + response.attack;
            });

        }
        console.log("result is " + total);
        return resolve(total);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Promise.all()`

```
function getTotalAttack(minionsIds) {
    return new Promise( function (resolve, reject) {

        var total = 0,
            queries$p=[]
        // if you need only to retrieve the documents :
        // queries$p = minions.find({_id:{$in:minionsIds}}).exec()

        // or if you need an extra instruction in between :
        minionsIds.forEach(function(mids) {
            console.log("sending one now");
            queries$p.push(minions.findById(mids).exec())
        });

        Promise.all(queries$p)
         .then( function(minions) { 
            minions.forEach(function(minion){ 
                total += minion.attack;
            })
            console.log("total attack:", total);       
            return resolve(total)
         })
         .catch( function(e) {
            return resolve(0)
         })
         ;
    });
}
```

From the MDN :

> Promise.all is rejected if one of the elements is rejected and
>   Promise.all fails fast: If you have four promises which resolve after
>   a timeout, and one rejects immediately, then Promise.all rejects
>   immediately.

Comment: How would The query be, when each of The data in input is The _id within? Like my code query was?

Comment: in var minion the result is 0

Comment: A common pitfall of JS :  ``for var i in A`` doesn't return the elements of A, but their indices.

Comment: can you change so if any of the ids dosent exist from the query, that it returns 0;? cause im having trouble with that now when im passing ids that dosent exist anymore.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for the sum of all the minions attacks, you can also perform it directly with mongo in one aggregation :

```
minion.aggregate(
   [{
      $group:{
        _id: null, 
        total:{$sum:"$attack"}
      }
   }]
).then( etc.. )
```

Comment: Yeah, but only those who i have The ID to will be summed

Comment: All of Them are in db, but i only want to Get The sum of those i have The ID to in my variable

Comment: Then you only need to add a ``{$match: { _id: { $in: minionsIds} }}`` before `` {$group:...}``

Comment: But Then I need to make a loop because I have up to 5 ids.

Comment: No loop : provides the array, returns the sum.

Comment: What if two of the ids don't longer exist in db? Would it then be the sum of 3, if the array were 5 ids?

Comment: yes : this will sum only the matching fields. Non-existent or non matching one wouldn't be counted. This is different than the first approach, where the result in 0 when there is an unmatched id.

Answer (score 0):

you make another async call from

```
minions.findOne({ _Id  : thisminion }).then( function(response){
            total = +total + response.attack;
        });
```

you should take all the ids in one time.
i think you use mongodb here? 
use $in
then you didnt need the for loop.

[mongodb $in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/)